# How not to lose dialog flow with chatbot v4?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have created a chatbot v4 with Microsoft Bot Framework and it was working fine. We have two environments QA and PROD. As time passed the bot has more functions and Dialogs.

We have discovered that in PROD (that has the same code as QA) it's not working fine, sometimes it exits from the current Dialog and returns to the init.

I have already tried to connect QnA QA base to PROD to see if it is a DB problem, but it hasn't solved the problem.

this is part of my code

in **Bot.cs**
in **OnTurnAsync**

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
{
    // Continue the current dialog
    var dialogResult = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();

    // examine results from active dialog
    switch (dialogResult.Status)
    {
        case DialogTurnStatus.Empty:
            await NewConversationFlow(turnContext, dc, conversationId, cancellationToken);
            break;

        case DialogTurnStatus.Waiting:
            // The active Dialog is waiting for a response from the user, so do nothing.
            break;

        case DialogTurnStatus.Complete:
            await dc.EndDialogAsync();
            // do things
            await NewConversationFlow(turnContext, dc, conversationId, cancellationToken);
            break;

        default:
            await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
            break;
    }
}
```

in **Bot.cs**
in **NewConversationFlow**

```
var response = await _services.QnAServices["QnA"].GetAnswersAsync(turnContext, new QnAMakerOptions() { Top = 5, ScoreThreshold = 0.1F });
QueryResult qnaAnswer = GetQnaAnswer(response, 0.60);

await _flowService.ShortDelayWithTypingActionAsync(turnContext);
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response.Answer, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

var flowValue = response.Metadata?.Where(metadata => metadata.Name == "flow").Select(metadata => metadata.Value).FirstOrDefault();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(flowValue))
{
    switch (flowValue)
    {
        case ONE:
        ...
        default:
            await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OneAnswerDialog));
            break;
        case TWO:
        ...
            await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(TwoAnswerDialog));
            break;
        case SEARCH:
            await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(SearchDialog));
            break;
    }
}
```

in **OneAnswerDialog**

```
// Dialog IDs
profileDialog = nameof(OneAnswerDialog);

// Add control flow dialogs
var firstCaseWaterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
{
            GetAnswerAsync,
            SearchStepAsync,
};
AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(profileDialog, firstCaseWaterfallSteps));
AddDialog(new TextPrompt(ResponsePrompt, ValidateResponseAsync));
```

Usually, it fails after that the user insert an answer after the first question (the one that is printed in NewConversationFlow). I don't know if it fails in **GetAnswerAsync** or if in **ValidateResponseAsync** because I can't debug the code in PRD.

in **GetAnswerAsync**

```
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(ResponsePrompt, new PromptOptions());
```

in **ValidateResponseAsync**

```
PositiveResponse = false;
var value = promptContext?.Recognized?.Value?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;

if (value != string.Empty)
{
    promptContext.Recognized.Value = value;

    bool userSayYes = false;
    var response = await _services.QnAServices["QnA"].GetAnswersAsync(promptContext.Context, new QnAMakerOptions() { Top = 5, ScoreThreshold = 0.1F });
    if (response != null && response.Length > 0)
    {
        var responses = response.Where(resp => resp.Metadata?.Any(metadata => metadata.Name == "metadata") ?? false).Select(x => x.Metadata);

        PositiveResponse = responses.Any(metadatas => metadatas.Any(metadata => metadata.Value == "more" || metadata.Value == "no"));
        if (!PositiveResponse && responses.Any(metadatas => metadatas.Any(metadata => metadata.Value == "yes")))
        {
            userSayYes = true;
            await _flowService.DelayWithTypingActionAsync(promptContext.Context);
            await promptContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Can I help you with anything else?", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    if (response == null || response.Length <= 0 || (!PositiveResponse && !userSayYes))
    {
        await _flowService.AddOrUpdateQuestion(promptContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.Id, value);
    }
    else if (userSayYes)
    {
        await _flowService.RemoveFlowTypeAndQuestion(promptContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.Id);
    }
}

return true;
```

(if PositiveResponse is false, in the successive pass the Dialog end and returns in Bot.cs)

For some reason in PROD the bot is "confused" and exit from the Dialog in **GetAnswerAsync** or **ValidateResponseAsync** and recall the **NewConversationFlow**.

I have read in another post that the delay with the dot typing can cause this problem, I have removed them but the problem persists...

What could be the problem?
What can cause a premature exit from a Dialog?

Thanks in advance.

**-------------------------- EDIT --------------------------**

I've tunnelled PRD with ngrok and debug it with VS, in this case, the bot it's working...

What can be? There is any Azure configuration that can cause it? I have already checked the billing plan and it isn't the free one.

**-------------------------- EDIT 2 --------------------------**

I have updated **GetAnswerAsync** to be sure to that the bot is entering in the Dialog:

```
protected async Task<DialogTurnResult> GetAnswerAsync(
                                        WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("What do you think? Does it answer your question?");
    await stepContext.PromptAsync(ResponsePrompt, new PromptOptions());
    return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
}
```

It seems to exit from the dialog at this point, when waiting the user prompt...

[image: chat with the bot]

("Oh, sorry to hear that!" Is chit chat, it's not the next step of the WaterFall)

Sometimes, the bot works. It seems to be something "random".

[image: Working flow]

**-------------------------- EDIT 3 --------------------------**
I still have this problem... I have tried to remove all the settings from Azure to force the app to read it from the file. I have used the same settings in PRD and QA but nothing... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In your "GetAnswerAsync" file, try replacing your code with the below snippet. I usually work in Node and occasionally I've experienced the dialog will "reset" if I only return the awaited "send" / "prompt" activity. If I explicitly send the `DialogTurnStatus`, then the flow moves as expected (i.e. on to the following step).

```cs
await stepContext.PromptAsync(ResponsePrompt, new PromptOptions());
return new DialogTurnStatus(DialogTurnStatus.waiting);
```

If not that, could the QnA response scores be too close to the .60 threshold in `GetQnaAnswer()`? Since results are non-deterministic (meaning the score *can* fluctuate from instance to instance), perhaps the response isn't always meeting the threshold?

Hope of help!

Comment: I have tried this but it isn't solved my problem. I have the limit of the ScoreThreshold set to 0.1... and I have already tried to change the QnA database with the QA database (where it works) and it doesn't work

Comment: What is happening in `case ONE` of your switch statement where you show "..."? And, do you have a `break` inserted there? Without a `break`, if there is a match on `case ONE` it will be executed, but the switch statement will continue to `default` and execute that, as well.

Comment: I used the dots to indicate various cases, I can't use the real name case here... it's like `case ONE: case ONE_A: case ONE_B: default: /*do things*/ break;` It's my intention that case ONE and default have the same behaviour.

Comment: This may be an aside, but why have a `case ONE`, then? Why not match on `case TWO`, etc., and if no match, then `default`?

Comment: Because I have more than a Dialog type. I have used the metadata in QnA (knowledge base),  and every "important" question have a different metadata value, for this reason, I have a case ONE_A, ONE_B, etc. I need to differentiate them successively in the dialog (same Dialog and behaviour but different answers). I'll make a change to verify that the bot is entering in the flow and I'll tell you.

Comment: It is entering in the Dialog, please check the main question I have updated it.

Comment: P.S. the default is the same case for the "ONE" type because if the answer in QnA has the metadata key as "flow" I need that at least enter in the first case. I hope I have answered all the questions :)

Comment: You mention when it exits prematurely, the dialog displayed is chit chat (e.g. "Oh, sorry to hear that!"). Where does this chit chat come from and how does it know to apply it? I'm wondering if whatever mechanism calls and displays the chit chat is somehow conflicting with your regular dialog flow.

Comment: That come from **Bot.cs** in **NewConversationFlow**. When the bot exit the Dialog it restarts the entire flow: **OnTurnAsync** -> **NewConversationFlow** -> eventually **OneAnswerDialog** (or other Dialog)